# Use Automator to move files to new folder based on list of filenames?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I'm not sure if this is something that Automator can do, and would really appreciate any pointers.

I'm working with a folder of ~4500 images. Based on some metadata that I have from another source, I want to move about a thousand of those images to a new folder (it's just too many to move by hand). I have a csv file that includes the names of the files to move, but I can't figure out how to get Automator to let me set the list as a criteria. The filenames are all randomly assigned strings of 32 numbers and letters, so I don't think this is a matter of filtering.

How would I go about moving ~1000 files from one folder to another using a csv/list? Maybe it's possible that Applescript is a good option, but I can't say I've ever looked there at all, so I'd be starting from scratch.

Comment: I wanted something similar a while back to process files - make copies, change bits, so I did a google search and many people have posted code that can be edited.

Comment: You definition of criteria to move a file confuses me. First you state *"Based on some metadata that I have from another source"*, then you state "*I have a csv file that includes the names of the files to move*". Also, does the csv file just contain the filenames or is there other that needs to be ignored?

Comment: Your question as currently written is impossible to give you any realistic guidance as there are too many unknowns!

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the following information... 1. What version of **macOS** are you running? 2. Where are the _files_ to move currently located and where do you want them moved to? 3. Are they all in one _folder_ and being moved to one other _folder_ or what? 4. Provide _fully qualified pathname_ of the locations. 5. Please show a few lines of the **CVS** _file_ and explain what it is your shown. 6. What is this "metadata that I have from another source" and how does it relate to the question? 7. Is the a one time thing or something that will be repetitive?

Answer (score 0):

To move files to another folder would not require the use of the Automator or Apple Script. You could accomplish this by entering commands in a Terminal application window.

### Example 1

Below is the contents of a file nameed `list.csv`. This file just contains the names of files to be moved to another folder.

```
file001,file002,file003
file004,file005
file006
```

From `bash`, the command below would move the files to a folder named `MyTarget`.

```
(IFS=,; while read -u 5 -a w; do for j in ${w[@]}; do mv -i "$j" MyTarget; done; done)5<list.csv
```

From `zsh`, the command would change to the following.

```
(IFS=,; while read -u 5 -A w; do for j in ${w[@]}; do mv -i "$j" MyTarget; done; done)5<list.csv
```

*Note:* You can do a dry-run by preceding the `mv` with `echo`. For `zsh`, the command would appear as shown below.

```
(IFS=,; while read -u 5 -A w; do for j in ${w[@]}; do echo mv -i "$j" MyTarget; done; done)5<list.csv
```

This command would produce the following output.

```
mv -i file001 MyTarget
mv -i file002 MyTarget
mv -i file003 MyTarget
mv -i file004 MyTarget
mv -i file005 MyTarget
mv -i file006 MyTarget
```

### Example 2

Below is the contents of a file nameed `list.csv`. Here, the name of a file to move is the second item on each line.

```
black,file001,yes,5
brown,file002,no,6
red,file003,no,7
orange,file004,yes,30
yellow,file005,no,3
green,file006,no,99
```

From `bash`, the command below would move the files to a folder named `MyTarget`.

```
(IFS=,; while read -u 5 -a w; do mv -i "${w[1]}" MyTarget; done)5<list.csv
```

From `zsh`, the command would change to the following.

```
(IFS=,; while read -u 5 -A w; do mv -i "${w[2]}" MyTarget; done)5<list.csv
```